# Repeat scrolling for HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

I want horizontalscrollview to repeat itself from beginning or in reverse direction from right to left. How can we achieve this. I have used Handler object for automatic scrolling.

```
android.widget.HorizontalScrollView horizontalScrollView1;

Handler mHandler = new Handler(new Callback() {

@Override
public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
    horizontalScrollView1.smoothScrollBy(1, 0);
    mHandler.sendMessageDelayed(new Message(), 20);
    return false;
}
});

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.horizontal_scroll_view);
horizontalScrollView1= (android.widget.HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView1);

mHandler.sendMessageDelayed(new Message(), 1000);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one of [those](https://www.google.com/search?q=android+move+horizontalscrollview+programmatically) could help you.